# Difference Between '?' and '*' in regular expressions

Tags: regex, lex, flex-lexer

I am learning regular expressions to use them in lex program. I've Seen [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) that, in Regular Expressions:

`'*' matches 0 or more occurances of pattern` 
`'?' matches 0 or 1 occurance of the pattern`

By this I'm kinda Confused. I mean:

if we can match 0 or more by **'*'** then why should we use **'?'** meta character?

We define Float as : `FL [0-9]*"."[0-9]+`

Can we define it as : `FL [0-9]?"."[0-9]+` for numbers like 0.999 or .999 etc (ie, Number with only one digit before radix point `.` )?

Can Any one please explain this? Thanking you in advance :).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to match 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, or more occurrences, use `*`.

If you *only* want to match 0 or 1 occurrences, use `?`.

For instance, consider this text: `"________starts with whitespace"`

If I want to match all of the underscores at the beginning of that text, but I don't want to require that they be there (they're optional), I'd use `_*`.

In contrast, if I to just match an optional *single* `+` in (say) `"+44 20 1234 5678"`, I'd use `\+?` (a literal `+` with the `?` after it). That will only match the single `+` or nothing, it would not match *multiple* `+` characters.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Will `FL [0-9]?"."[0-9]+` Work for finding floats ?

Comment: @VedantTerkar: I don't know the specific dialect of regex you're using, so those quotes look odd to me. But that's probably not correct, because if I'm reading it right, it would *not* match `23.5` because you've only allowed a *single* digit before the `.`. So you'd probably want `*` rather than `?` there, so you match any number of digits before the `.`.

Comment: I'm Using flex and DevCPP on windows 7 and `FL [0-9]*"."[0-9]+` works for me. but If I want to accept only one digit before `.` as you've said. Then can `FL [0-9]?"."[0-9]+` solve this?

Comment: @VedantTerkar: Right, `[0-9]?` means "zero or one digits, but not two or more". `[0-9]*` means "zero or more digits (no limit, could be 42 of them)". Note that some languages require that floats are written with a leading `0` before the `.` if the number is between `0` and `1` (`0.5` not `.5`), others don't, I don't know which kind you're trying to validate.